# trying to access jconsole mbean value

Tags: java, jmx, mbeans

I am trying to access MBean values through jmx and specifically getMBeanServerConnection. The tree setup in jconsole is difficult to traverse and I need some help with getting the values I specifically need or be able to get all the type,name and attributes. Here is what I have used to read the jmx mbean values:

```
//get an instance of the kafka metrics Mbean
            consumerBeanII = 
 jmxCon.getMBeanServerConnection().getAttribute(new 
 ObjectName("kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,
    name=MessagesInPerSec,topic=data.in"),"MeanRate");
            System.out.println(" Message Mean Rate: " + consumerBeanII); 
// this works

  consumerBean = jmxCon.getMBeanServerConnection().getAttribute(new 
  ObjectName("kafka.server:type=FetcherLagMetrics,
     name=ConsumerLag,side=ReplicaFetcherThread-0- 
            2,topic=data.in"),"Value");
            System.out.println(" ConsumerLag: " + consumerBean); 
 //this does not work and throws exception
```

Error:

```
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: 
kafka.server:type=FetcherLagMetrics,name=ConsumerLag,
side=ReplicaFetcherThread-0-2,topic=data.in
```

Now here is a snapshot of the jconsole tree and hierarchy:

[image]

so its basically as follows:

```
kafka.server --->  FetcherLagMetrics  -->  ConsumerLag --->  
  ReplicaFetcherThread-0-2 ---> data.in  ---> 5 ---> Attributes ---> 
  Value
```

There are multiple subfolders under ConsumerLag  (ReplicateFetcherThread .*) and then all the topics under each of those folders. But it seems the value = 0 for all which is a separate issue anyway. Any advise or assistance appreciated

Comment: I am also getting similar issue... You got any solution?